# Why does electron respond almost instantaneously on nucleus' displacement due to the difference in mass of it and the nucleus?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, born-oppenheimer-approximation

In Born Oppenheimer Approximation, we take note of the great difference between the mass of the electrons and nuclei. But, I have not been able to understand this statement quoted from *Molecular Quantum Mechanics* by *Atkins* and *Friedman*; *An introduction to Molecular Structure*'s *The Born-Oppenheimer approximation*:

> [...] Because of this difference, the electrons can respond almost instantaneously to displacement of the nuclei.

What does it really mean ?

Comment: 1. Whenever you quote a statement, *give the source you cited it from*. 2. Include a bit more context - what "displacement" are we asking about here, and what kind of "response"?

Comment: It is from Molecular Quantum Mechanics by Atkins and Friedman.

Answer (score 2):

The argument is that is a particle has lover mass it will be more easily effected by external forces.

Since the electrons are ~1000 times lighter than atomic nuclei it means that they also move on time-scale that are ~1000 faster.

Thus any change to the nuclear positions will be very slow from the point of view of the electrons and so one can assume that the electrons react instantly this change.

Answer (score 1):

Reading on the [Born Oppenheimer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born%E2%80%93Oppenheimer_approximation) approximation

> The Born–Oppenheimer (BO) approximation is ubiquitous in quantum chemical calculations of molecular wavefunctions. It consists of two steps.
>
> In the first step the nuclear kinetic energy is neglected,[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born%E2%80%93Oppenheimer_approximation) that is, the corresponding operator Tn is subtracted from the total molecular Hamiltonian. In the remaining electronic Hamiltonian He the nuclear positions enter as parameters. The electron–nucleus interactions are not removed and the electrons still "feel" the Coulomb potential of the nuclei clamped at certain positions in space.

It is really the assumption that the center of mass of the whole system is on the nucleus position.  As the other answer points out that is not off because of the great difference in the masses of the protons and neutrons to the mass of the electrons.

If the position of the nucleus varies it carries off the electrons because the center of mass is sitting on the nucleus, i.e. the moving frame and the center of mass frame coincided within errors. If  not, the approximation will fail.

Comment: I don't think this answer is right. The BO is not about the center of mass, but about the fact that to solve the electrons' dynamics, one can assume that the nuclei are static. Then the dynamics of the nuclei is solved when the electrons have been integrated out.

Comment: @Adam  Static nuclei present the same problem as a ball with a wall. The wall is static, the ball moves, the center of mass is in the wall. The center of mass system and any  "vibrating wall +ball"  have no difference because of the great mass of the wall where huge momenta will be needed to have the center of mass outside the wall. All problems are solved simply  in the center of mass system, except in this case it coincides with the lab.